# How do I "smart shuffle" rows in a SQLite database?

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have an sqlite .db file that holds a bunch of data for my music library. There's a table called 'songs' with columns like 'genre', 'artist', 'length', and so on. I run a select query that filters my collection down to a handful of artists. I start with something like this:

select * where artist = 'MyArtist' or comment like '%Keyword%'

Most artists show up 1 to 10 times, but one artist, MyArtist, has about 50 songs. I want to shuffle this data so that:

- The one artist with the most songs is distributed evenly, meaning that if there are 200 rows, this artist comes up every 4 iterations. If there are 150 rows, it comes up every third entry, and so on.
- The other artists are shuffled. You don't get two artists in a row, if possible.
- Songs are distributed based on length. Songs that are 7 minutes long won't play back-to-back, and ones that are less than two minutes won't play back to back.

What would I need to add to my query to get this result that I want, a kind of algorithmic shuffle?

Comment: Have you considered just doing a random ordering?  This would tend to give you the results you want, with the caveat that, e.g., two lengthy songs might  occasionally play next to each other, etc.

Comment: How is MySQL related to this question?

Comment: I removed the `mysql` tag as the question states `sqlite`

Comment: Use `ORDER BY RANDOM`

Comment: I tried order by random() but this makes the results truly random. I'm looking for more of a 'shuffle' where rows with the same value in the 'artists' column aren't grouped together and MyArtist is evenly distributed among the rows.